# Two parameter function containing a loop and zip function

Tags: python-2.7

Create a function that takes a string and a list as parameters. The string should contain the first ten letters of the alphabet and the list should contain the corresponding numbers for each letter. Zip the string and list into a list of tuples that pair each letter and number. The function should then print the number and corresponding letter respectively on separate lines. Hint: Use the zip function and a loop!

I have this so far:
def alphabet_num(letters, numbers):
    for x in letters, numbers:
        print zip(letters, numbers)

alphabet_num("abcdefghij", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the zip function inside a loop, zip takes two lists and zips them together for you into a list of tuples (ie it doesn't take two elements and zip them into a single tuple). Then what you want to do is loop through the zipped list (list of tuples) printing out the letter (first thing in the tuple) and then the number (second thing in the tuple).

```
def alphabet_num(letters, numbers): 
    zipped = zip(letters, numbers)
    for (x,y) in zipped:
        print x
        print y
```